# Pandas optimizing an interpolation/counting algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, pandas

I have a bunch of data (10M + records) that breaks down to an identifier, a location and a date. I want to find the number of times that any identifier moved from some locationA to some other locationB over the entire set of dates. Any identifier may not have a location for all possible dates. When an identifier does not have a location recorded, that should be treated as an actual 'unknown' location for that date.

Here is some reproducible fake data...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

base = datetime.date.today()
num_days = 50
dates = np.array([base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_days-1, -1, -1)])
ids = np.arange(50)
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ids, dates])
locations = np.array([chr(x) for x in 97 + np.random.randint(26, size=len(mi))])

s = pd.Series(locations, index=mi)
mask = np.random.rand(len(mi)) > .5
s[mask] = np.nan
s = s.dropna()
```

My initial thought was to create a dataframe and use boolean masking/vectorized operations to solve this

```
df = s.unstack(0).fillna('unknown')
```

Apparently my data is sparse enough to cause a MemoryError (from all the extra entries resulting from unstacking).

My current working solution is the following

```
def series_fn(s):
    s = s.reindex(pd.date_range(s.index.levels[1].min(), s.index.levels[1].max()), level=-1).fillna('unknown')
    mask_prev = (s != s.shift(-1))[:-1]
    mask_next = (s != s.shift())[1:]
    s_prev = s[:-1][mask_prev]
    s_next = s[1:][mask_next]
    s_tup = pd.Series(list(zip(s_prev, s_next)))
    return s_tup.value_counts()

result_per_id = s.groupby(level=0).apply(series_fn)
result = result_per_id.sum(level=-1)
```

`result` looks like

```
(a, b)    1
(a, c)    5
(a, e)    3
(a, f)    3
(a, g)    3
(a, h)    3
(a, i)    1
(a, j)    1
(a, k)    2
(a, l)    2
...
```

This is going to take ~5 hours for all my data. Does anyone know any faster ways of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the data already sorted by date?

Comment: It can be.. that's not really a bottleneck in pandas.

Comment: I was wondering if you acquired it in date order from the sensors, for instance. IIRC once you can assume that, cheap algorithms are more likely -- e.g. iterate through the file keeping track of `last seen AT and ON_DATE' for each ID, spitting out a change whenever AT updates or ON_DATE shows a gap.

Comment: Hmm good point... Doesn't take advantage of vectorized ops though. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I guess I should have transposed the data... well that was a relatively simple fix. Instead of using groupby and apply,

```
s = s.reorder_levels(['date', 'id'])
s = s.sortlevel(0)

results = []

for i in range(len(s.index.levels[0])-1):
    t = time.time()
    s0 = s.loc[s.index.levels[0][i]]
    s1 = s.loc[s.index.levels[0][i+1]]
    df = pd.concat((s0, s1), axis=1)

    # Note: this is slower than the line above
    # df = s.loc[s.index.levels[0][0:2], :].unstack(0)

    df = df.fillna('unknown')
    mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1]))
    s2 = pd.Series(1, mi)
    res = s2.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(np.sum)
    results.append(res)
    print(time.time() - t)

results = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
```

Still unclear on why the commented out section takes about three times as long as the three lines above it.